# I have to match php variable in php file

Tags: php

I have to match php variable in the php file using `preg_match()`

`$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['enjay_host_list'] = array (`

How can I do this.

I am doing,

```
<?php
$filename='/var/www/su/custom/include/language/en_us.lang.php';
$fileopen=file($filename);
        //echo $fileopen[2];
$NoOflines = count($fileopen);
echo $NoOflines ."<br>";
$Changed=0;
$Foundon=0;
$FoundFirstClose=0;
        for($i=0;$i<$NoOflines;$i++)
        {
                echo $fileopen[$i]."<br>";
                 if(preg_match("/\$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['enjay_host_list']=array ( /i", $fileopen[$i]))
                 {
                    $Foundon=$i;
                    echo $fileopen[$i]."<br>";
                 }

        }
?>
```

Comment: escape the square brackets in your regex with \\[ and \\], since these will be interpreted as character classes

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape every character that has a special meaning in a regexp, which means not only the `$` but also `[`, `]` and `(`. See the PCRE documentation for the [list of special characters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) in pcre regexp.

Another issue is that because you use double quotes, php tries to replace `$GLOBALS..` with a variable content unless you double backslash it on top of it, so it's better to just use the [Nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) syntax (if you use php >= 5.3, which you really should).

```
$pattern = <<<'EOS'
/\$GLOBALS\['app_list_strings'\]\['enjay_host_list'\]=array \( /i
EOS;

for($i=0;$i<$NoOflines;$i++)
{
    echo $fileopen[$i]."<br>";
    if(preg_match($pattern, $fileopen[$i]))
    {
        $Foundon=$i;
        echo $fileopen[$i]."<br>";
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your missing some escape characters in your regular expression.

```
"/\$GLOBALS\['app_list_strings'\]\['enjay_host_list'\]=array\s\(/i"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "\$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['enjay_host_list']=array (" ;
$match = preg_match("/\\\$GLOBALS\['app\_list\_strings'\]\['enjay\_host\_list'\]\s*=\s*array\s*\(/i", $string);

var_dump($match) ;
```

Possible issues with your regexp:

1. You have to escape special chars as ([]_$)
2. You have to double escape `$` sign when using double quotes in PHP
3. Whitespaces are also important. I used `\s*` which correspons to  0 or more whitespaces.